# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE throws SQL error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have a SQL Query that uses ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as:

**QUERY UPDATED :**

```
    MERGE INTO reports rt
  USING (SELECT REPORT_ID,TITLE,CATEGORY,DISPLAY_ORDER,QUERY,DESCRIPTION,CONTENT_SEQ,DELD,ADMIN_ID
           FROM reports) rs
     ON (rt.report_id = rs.report_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET rt.TITLE = 'a',
                rt.CATEGORY = 'z',
                rt.DISPLAY_ORDER= 9,
                rt.QUERY ='q',
                rt.DESCRIPTION='d',
                rt.CONTENT_SEQ=1,
                rt.DELD=0,
                rt.ADMIN_ID=1
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
     INSERT(REPORT_ID,TITLE,CATEGORY,DISPLAY_ORDER,QUERY,DESCRIPTION,CONTENT_SEQ,DELD,ADMIN_ID)
       VALUES(27,
        'a',
        'z',
        9,
        'q',
        'd',
        1,
        0,
        1;
```

When I run this query it throws an error : `SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.`

P.S : I am using Oracle Database.

Is it that it wont support 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' clause ? 
If No,what is the other option to achieve this ?

Comment: Use the Merge statement  - don't think Oracle supports 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' clause

Comment: Yeah, don't let the fact that [there's documentation on Oracle's site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/insert-on-duplicate.html) about it confuse you—although it's hard to tell from looking at that page, that's [MySQL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/index.html) (Oracle own MySQL.)

Comment: Please remove the snapshot and include the query as text and add code tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using Oracle Database.
>
> Is it that it wont support 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' clause ? If
>   No,what is the other option to achieve this ?

Probably it is a **MySQL** supported feature. Oracle doesn't support **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**. You need to use a **MERGE** statement.

For example,

```
MERGE INTO dest_table t
  USING (SELECT <column_list> 
           FROM source_table) s
     ON (t.col1 = s.col1) -- use required join keys
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET t.<column_list> = s.<column_list>
                ...
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
     INSERT( t.<column_list>)
       VALUES( s.<column_list>)
```

Read the documentation for more details on [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606). Few examples [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g.php).

**Update** Based on OP's new query in the edited question.

> ```
> WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN     INSERT(REPORT_ID,TITLE,CATEGORY,DISPLAY_ORDER,QUERY,DESCRIPTION,CONTENT_SEQ,DELD,ADMIN_ID)
>        VALUES(27,
>         'a',
>         'z',
>         9,
>         'q',
>         'd',
>         1,
>         0,
>         1;
> ```

There is a closing brace missing in the end before the semi-colon. Try this:

```
MERGE INTO reports rt 
USING (SELECT report_id, 
              title, 
              category, 
              display_order, 
              query, 
              description, 
              content_seq, 
              deld, 
              admin_id 
       FROM   reports) rs 
ON (rt.report_id = rs.report_id) 
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE SET rt.title = 'a', 
             rt.category = 'z', 
             rt.display_order = 9, 
             rt.query = 'q', 
             rt.description = 'd', 
             rt.content_seq = 1, 
             rt.deld = 0, 
             rt.admin_id = 1 
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
  INSERT(report_id, 
         title, 
         category, 
         display_order, 
         query, 
         description, 
         content_seq, 
         deld, 
         admin_id) 
  VALUES(27, 
         'a', 
         'z', 
         9, 
         'q', 
         'd', 
         1, 
         0, 
         1);
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit !
I have added a snapshot of the query built on the template you have provided. 
However,I am not sure as to what Destination and source table I should specify as  I am dealing with only one table(reports).

This does not runs and throws : ORA-38102: Invalid column in the INSERT WHERE Clause: "RT"."REPORT_ID" 

PLEASE HELP ! 
Thanks :)

Comment: Please remove the snapshot and include the query as text and add code tags.

Comment: The above code do updates the Records. 
However it does not Inserts new record . 
Any idea where we are going wrong ? 
It shows : 0 rows merged.

Comment: 0 rows merged means there are no rows updated or inserted at all. Check the join condition in the ON clause properly. See the USING clause whether it is correct or not.